# How to use angularjs routeProvider with MVC plugins

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm working on an plugin-based MVC application and I want to use angularjs as route provider. (I'm newbie in angular.) I have specified the necessary information in my app.js and it's working properly for those views, which are in the same project (i.e. /home):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'Home/Index',
            controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'Plugin.App/Home/About',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: 'Home/SomeLocation'
        });
});

app.controller('mainController', mainController);
app.controller('aboutController', aboutController);
```

But, when I tried to locate any partial view from my plugin, I got 404. Do you have any suggestion to solve this situation?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Craig85

Comment: You're using _either_ ASP.NET MVC routing which means server-side routing, or Angular routing which means routing is done on the client side. If you're doing routes in Angular you need to rewrite all urls to other routes  to go to your index file and let Angular deal with the routing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Benjamin! In this case, I would have to specify only one view in every plugin and this should be the Index. Am I right?

Comment: does your asp.net home controller has index method?

Comment: Yes, my Home controller has Index method and every other plugin has an Index method in the corresponding controller.

Comment: @Craig85  change home $route url from `templateUrl: 'Home/Index',` to `templateUrl: '/Home/Index',` & otherwise code should be `.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
        })`

Comment: @pankajparkar Thanks for your suggestion, but it's working for internal views (for example 'Home/Index'). The problem is with the views from my plugins.

Comment: @Craig85 are you able to call plugin controller from URL? if yes then what is the URL to call the plugin `Home` controller

Comment: Actually, I can't, but I can render them with @Html.Partial().

Comment: what url you are giving in `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: It seems, there is a bug in my plugin framework. The issue is not related to the angular anymore. Thanks for your suggestions!